# WFLYSRV0220: Server shutdown has been requested

Tags: wildfly, production, wildfly-9

I am using wildfly-9.0.0.CR2 server for my Spring MVC application, on a sudden wildfly server stooping for every 10 mins!. I don't think my application is requesting server for shutdown and I didn't use any third party APIs.

When I observe the server log I couldn't figure out the issue.

```
2018-12-05 12:36:57,438 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-2) WFLYSRV0220: Server shutdown has been requested.
2018-12-05 12:36:57,466 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = DCTWebApp.war_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1
2018-12-05 12:36:57,477 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:/thalesdbDocTool]
2018-12-05 12:36:57,477 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:/thalesdbtool]
2018-12-05 12:36:57,498 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: /
2018-12-05 12:36:57,528 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher'
2018-12-05 12:36:57,538 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Wed Dec 05 12:29:45 IST 2018]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
2018-12-05 12:36:57,575 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2018-12-05 12:36:57,582 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Dec 05 12:29:35 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-12-05 12:36:57,598 ERROR [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) Destroy method on bean with name '(inner bean)#305d8fe1' threw an exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.BaseClientDetails.hashCode(BaseClientDetails.java:279)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.replaceNode(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1106)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.remove(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1097)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeDestruction(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:239)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:900)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:589)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:900)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:907)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:884)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:836)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:579)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextDestroyed(ApplicationListeners.java:185)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentImpl.destroy(DeploymentImpl.java:224)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.undeploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:578)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.stopContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:145)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$2.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:121)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)

2018-12-05 12:36:57,604 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = mysql
2018-12-05 12:36:57,803 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0019: Host default-host stopping
2018-12-05 12:36:57,822 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
2018-12-05 12:36:57,838 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = h2
2018-12-05 12:36:57,855 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTP listener default suspending
2018-12-05 12:36:57,860 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTPS listener default-ssl suspending
2018-12-05 12:36:57,863 INFO  [oinfluncerg.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTP listener default stopped, was bound to localhost/127.0.0.1:4714
2018-12-05 12:36:57,870 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTPS listener default-ssl stopped, was bound to localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
2018-12-05 12:36:57,886 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0004: Undertow 1.2.8.Final stopping
2018-12-05 12:36:57,925 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment DCTWebApp.war (runtime-name: DCTWebApp.war) in 472ms
2018-12-05 12:36:57,941 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0050: WildFly Full 9.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.0.Final) stopped in 473ms
```

Please help me to understand what could influence the server shutdown.

Comment: Are there other error logs into your server? (like hs_err*.log). Please, add the log information of the /var/log/wildfly/console.log file to the question

Comment: @ThiagoChagas Nothing like that, I don't have any error log

Comment: look at the kernel log, it could be oom killer that is stopping it for you

Comment: @ctomc thanks for the replay, let me check this and conform